# Wordpress post_type=post not excluding pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

this is my query

```
Select
$queryStringKeyWords
as my_rate,
`wp_posts`.*
from `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' OR `post_status` = 'future'
AND `post_type` = 'post'
order by my_rate desc limit 0, 10
```

but i get pages back. Why?

Comment: You should not run custom sql queries. Rather make use of `WP_Query`, `pre_get_posts` or `get_posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting parenthesis around your where

```
WHERE (`post_status` = 'publish' OR `post_status` = 'future')
```

Parenthesis help when doing more complex stuff like combining WHERE OR || AND OR

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `'` instead of ` in your query:

```
Select
$queryStringKeyWords
as my_rate,
'wp_posts'.*
from 'wp_posts'
WHERE 'post_status' = 'publish' OR 'post_status' = 'future'
AND 'post_type' = 'post'
order by my_rate desc limit 0, 10
```